# Can the face bones be "compressed" or forced together? What would happen?

Tags: cell-biology, metabolism, bone-biology, bone

Say someone doesn't like that their maxilla bone is too long because the height of the maxilla affects the placement, position and angle of the mandible relatively.

**If one were to apply mechanical force from the mandible underneath the hand (pushing up) while countering the force either with the neck and/or pulling the head forward and down for prolonged periods of time, steadily and consistently, will the maxilla literally move upwards?**

[image]

Simply put, as I understand it, bones remodeled due to consistent mechanical tension and stress placed on them lifelong as part of osteoblastic/osteoclastic activity and bone metabolism. My question is, assuming my line of thinking here is right, would the maxilla actually move upwards and the mandible will rotate too? How far up can it go before it would affect facial structure in a negative and/or potentially dangerous way, and how long would this take to do if done 1-2 hours per day, 7 days a week with about 1-4 lbs. of consistent, balanced and equalized force?

Comment: What's with the premaxilla? What do you think will happen to your teeth? And with you sinuses? And your nasals? 1-2 hours a day won't help anything... This won't act like plastic surgery...

Comment: Time under tension has to make some physical changes given enough duration. Doubting that would be doubting the science surrounding bone re-absorption and Wolff's Law.

Comment: Yes, there will be some effects... But not the ones you are looking for.. Or are you looking for terrible tooth ache and a missing occlusion? I don't doubt the effects... I work with biomechanics. There's something called the phenomenon of the blind billard player... He only sees the cue ball but isn't aware of the effects on the other balls when he hits the cue ball with the billard cue.

Comment: Please don't encourage this kind of question. This is a personal medical question, common among people who frequent incel forums.

Comment: It's a serious question and not personal/medical. What does its relation to incel forums have to do with anything? It's a fairly legitimate question about bones/biology/biomechanics/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Bones are remodelled,it's correct but there is a limit too in this remodelling and specially when are doing it manually. Moreover it is very important  to keep your jaws in proper occlusion otherwise this improper way of pressuring and tension creation in your maxilla and mandible will lead to more severe problems in your temperomandibular joint, leading you further to the cranial disorders. Such activities on a daily basis are quite harmful and these definitely don't work like plastic surgery. So, it's better not to perform these or it may lead you to become a regular patient to your dentist. If you are really willing to have such changes then you should consult a cosmetic surgeon.

Comment: I get your point, but this is more of a "what will happen" kind of question. Cosmetic surgeons charge money -- this experiment is 100% free so there's an advantage there.

Comment: For whom? The dentist?